# uisearchbar iphone how to get string

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

i have a question regarding uisearchbar for the iphone. How can i get access to the string the user is typing in the search bar and store it in a separate NSString, so it updates for every keystroke entered?

Answer (score 0):

You setup the UISearchBar [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to a object that implements the [UISearchBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate) interface.

The method 'searchBar:textDidChange:' is called whenever the text in the search bar is changed.